# Blender doesn't launch

Tags: blend-files

I recently installed Blender(2.82) on Steam and when I wento to run it, Blender simply flashed a grey window and didn't launch! Can someone please help me?

Comment: Make sure that your system fulfills the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.82.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem on Ubuntu - 2.8 didn't want to start up. 2.79 however works fine. This problem may be caused by GPU requirements. I had this problem on a laptop with an integrated GPU...